# Error connect to https://registry.npmjs.org whenever i try to download a package using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

OS - Window 11
NPM version 8.1.0
I am not behind any proxy.There'no antivirus install. I tried to use npm install a package then it gives me this error. I have tried alot of solutions changing the registry something.
I also tried and reinstall npm and tried the command on my another device but it all gave me same error connecting to https://registry.npmjs.org.

```
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'mysql'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.0
2 info using node@v16.13.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 9ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 16ms
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
27 timing idealTree:init Completed in 7ms
28 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
29 silly idealTree buildDeps
30 silly fetch manifest mysql@*
31 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql 71493ms (cache stale)
32 silly placeDep ROOT mysql@2.18.1 OK for:  want: *
33 silly fetch manifest bignumber.js@9.0.0
34 silly fetch manifest readable-stream@2.3.7
35 silly fetch manifest safe-buffer@5.1.2
36 silly fetch manifest sqlstring@2.3.1
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlstring 73549ms (cache stale)
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 73560ms (cache stale)
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js 73713ms (cache stale)
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer 73748ms (cache stale)
41 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 145253ms
42 silly placeDep ROOT bignumber.js@9.0.0 OK for: mysql@2.18.1 want: 9.0.0
43 silly placeDep ROOT readable-stream@2.3.7 OK for: mysql@2.18.1 want: 2.3.7
44 silly placeDep ROOT safe-buffer@5.1.2 OK for: mysql@2.18.1 want: 5.1.2
45 silly placeDep ROOT sqlstring@2.3.1 OK for: mysql@2.18.1 want: 2.3.1
46 silly fetch manifest core-util-is@~1.0.0
47 silly fetch manifest inherits@~2.0.3
48 silly fetch manifest isarray@~1.0.0
49 silly fetch manifest process-nextick-args@~2.0.0
50 silly fetch manifest string_decoder@~1.1.1
51 silly fetch manifest util-deprecate@~1.0.1
52 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 71417ms (cache stale)
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray 71472ms (cache stale)
54 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is 71479ms (cache stale)
55 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder 71479ms (cache stale)
56 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args 71481ms (cache stale)
57 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate 71480ms (cache stale)
58 timing idealTree:node_modules/mysql Completed in 71494ms
59 timing idealTree:node_modules/bignumber.js Completed in 0ms
60 silly placeDep ROOT core-util-is@1.0.3 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~1.0.0
61 silly placeDep ROOT inherits@2.0.4 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~2.0.3
62 silly placeDep ROOT isarray@1.0.0 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~1.0.0
63 silly placeDep ROOT process-nextick-args@2.0.1 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~2.0.0
64 silly placeDep ROOT string_decoder@1.1.1 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~1.1.1
65 silly placeDep ROOT util-deprecate@1.0.2 OK for: readable-stream@2.3.7 want: ~1.0.1
66 timing idealTree:node_modules/readable-stream Completed in 9ms
67 timing idealTree:node_modules/core-util-is Completed in 1ms
68 timing idealTree:node_modules/inherits Completed in 0ms
69 timing idealTree:node_modules/isarray Completed in 0ms
70 timing idealTree:node_modules/process-nextick-args Completed in 0ms
71 timing idealTree:node_modules/safe-buffer Completed in 0ms
72 timing idealTree:node_modules/sqlstring Completed in 0ms
73 timing idealTree:node_modules/string_decoder Completed in 0ms
74 timing idealTree:node_modules/util-deprecate Completed in 0ms
75 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 216758ms
76 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
77 timing idealTree Completed in 216768ms
78 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 216770ms
79 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 1ms
80 silly reify moves {}
81 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
82 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 6ms
83 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
84 silly audit bulk request {
84 silly audit   mysql: [ '2.18.1' ],
84 silly audit   'bignumber.js': [ '9.0.0' ],
84 silly audit   'readable-stream': [ '2.3.7' ],
84 silly audit   'safe-buffer': [ '5.1.2' ],
84 silly audit   sqlstring: [ '2.3.1' ],
84 silly audit   'core-util-is': [ '1.0.3' ],
84 silly audit   inherits: [ '2.0.4' ],
84 silly audit   isarray: [ '1.0.0' ],
84 silly audit   'process-nextick-args': [ '2.0.1' ],
84 silly audit   string_decoder: [ '1.1.1' ],
84 silly audit   'util-deprecate': [ '1.0.2' ]
84 silly audit }
85 silly tarball no local data for process-nextick-args@https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args/-/process-nextick-args-2.0.1.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
86 silly tarball no local data for inherits@https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.4.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
87 silly tarball no local data for readable-stream@https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-2.3.7.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
88 timing reifyNode:node_modules/core-util-is Completed in 62ms
89 timing reifyNode:node_modules/util-deprecate Completed in 65ms
90 timing reifyNode:node_modules/safe-buffer Completed in 65ms
91 timing reifyNode:node_modules/isarray Completed in 65ms
92 timing reifyNode:node_modules/string_decoder Completed in 67ms
93 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sqlstring Completed in 66ms
94 timing reifyNode:node_modules/bignumber.js Completed in 79ms
95 timing reifyNode:node_modules/mysql Completed in 121ms
96 silly audit bulk request failed undefined
97 verbose audit error FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
97 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
97 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
97 verbose audit error     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
97 verbose audit error     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
97 verbose audit error     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
97 verbose audit error     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
97 verbose audit error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
97 verbose audit error  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
97 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
97 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
97 verbose audit error     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
97 verbose audit error     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
97 verbose audit error     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
97 verbose audit error     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
97 verbose audit error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
97 verbose audit error   code: 'ECONNRESET',
97 verbose audit error   errno: 'ECONNRESET',
97 verbose audit error   syscall: 'read',
97 verbose audit error   type: 'system'
97 verbose audit error }
98 silly audit error undefined
99 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 968ms
100 silly audit report null
101 timing reify:audit Completed in 968ms
102 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 19ms
103 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
104 timing command:install Completed in 288287ms
105 verbose type system
106 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args/-/process-nextick-args-2.0.1.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
106 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
106 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
106 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
106 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)
106 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
106 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
106 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
107 verbose cwd C:\Users\User
108 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
109 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
110 verbose node v16.13.0
111 verbose npm  v8.1.0
112 error code ECONNRESET
113 error syscall read
114 error errno ECONNRESET
115 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args/-/process-nextick-args-2.0.1.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
116 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
116 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
116 error network
116 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
116 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
117 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: It might be your internet connection is too slow or the package does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If having problem with node version or any package version run these 3 commands:

```bash
npx npm-check-updates

npx npm-check-updates -u

nom install
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34844149)